# macOS Ventura can't find Apple's software update servers

Tags: macos, software-update, ventura

I recently upgraded my 2019 MacBook Pro to Ventura and am now hitting a couple of issues with Apple software updates that I think are related.

When I run `Xcode-select --install` it fails with a **Can't download the software because of a network problem** error.

In the Software Update preference pane it looks like it's forgotten the URL for Apple's software update servers:

[image]

I tried `sudo defaults read /Library/Preferences/com.apple.SoftwareUpdate CatalogURL` but got `The domain/default pair of (/Library/Preferences/com.apple.SoftwareUpdate, CatalogURL) does not exist`, which I understand means there's no local override in place to use my employer's servers for updates rather than Apple's.

How can I fix this please?

Comment: Have you tried `sudo softwareupdate --clear-catalog`. ??

Comment: Yes, it says `Catalog management is no longer supported.`

Comment: Is this Mac likely to have been enrolled in a company's Mobile Device Management scheme?

Comment: It used to be enrolled with VMware Intelligent Hub MDM software, but this was decommissioned. I'm wondering if the process of doing so wiped out the software update URL.

Comment: Hmm. You don't know what else might be skewy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try forcibly setting the catalogURL value:

```
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.SoftwareUpdate CatalogURL https://swscan.apple.com/content/catalogs/others/index-13-12-10.16-10.15-10.14-10.13-10.12-10.11-10.10-10.9-mountainlion-lion-snowleopard-leopard.merged-1.sucatalog.gz
```

Comment: @JohnTopley NB: Given that the default condition of that .plist is "no value"; I'm not sure what will happen when OS 14 comes out.